# Run commandline command at remote Oracle server using SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a machine running Oracle 10g server in windows server 2008. I want to take backup of the database. I also want to take backup of some files saved on hard disk by oracle server that users have uploaded using my website.

I can connect to the Oracle server using sql developer and sqlplus. I can run sql queries on the server.

In order to take backup of database I have to run the command "exp" (this is the only way of taking backup of databases that I know). There might be some other way but there is another problem because of which I must run dos command. That problem is to take backup of files. These files are stored in c:\mydir. The folder mydir is not accessible anyway through web and is not a shared folder.

I have tried running "host " in sqlplus after connecting to oracle server, that is at "sql>" prompt. The command ran successfuly but at local machine, not at oracle server.

Edit: The "host" command is provided by sqlplus and is not an oracle command, means cannot be used in a query. Sqlplus even when connected to remote machine run the "host" command at local machine.

The target is to either make sqlplus run the "host" command at remote machine, Or run the dos command from inside a pl/sql query (independent of sqlplus).

Comment: what kind of files do you need to back up from c:\mydir?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Justin has written:

If you want to take a logical snapshot of the database the new [DataPump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm) tool is preferred over the old (and deprecated) `exp` tool.

DataPump is a commandline tool (`expdp`) but also has a SQL API through Oracle packages and procedures.

[The Data Pump API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_api.htm) (including examples) 
[DBMS_DATAPUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm) (reference)

But if you want a "real" backup you should look into [RMAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/toc.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a Java stored procedure on the database server that executes an [operating system command on the Oracle server](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241).  But it would be extremely unusual to use the export utility to backup a database-- that only creates a logical backup not a more appropriate physical backup.  And it would be extremely unusual to run a backup by connecting to the database via SQL*Plus and spawning a job on the server operating system.  It would make much more sense to create a job using the Windows scheduler on the database server that ran whatever export commands you want to run.

Comment: @Atif - The Java stored procedure is identical whether the database runs on Windows or on Unix.  The operating system command that gets executed will, of course, be different.

Comment: Thanks for helping. How to revoke the permissions granted?

Comment: @Atif - If you are talking about the privileges that you need to grant to the Java stored procedure, you would make the equivalent `dbms_java.revoke_permission` call.